# Proxmox: Logical Volume missing after reboot

Tags: debian, lvm, virtual-machine, proxmox

initial situation: having a proxmox instance with an 6 TB HDD (for my media) setup with lvm to be able to expand.I just created an LV in Proxmox for my media, so I called it "Media". I had to reboot my Proxmox server and now my LV is missing.

I just tried to find the LV (`lvdisplay`), the VG (`vgdisplay`) or the PV (`pvdisplay`). But there isn't anything about. Therefore i figured out, that the internal device name of my 6 TB HDD changed.

`cat /etc/lvm/backup/Media` gives the following result:

```
            pv0 {
                    id = "AsxXXj-vOac-0laq-BoFU-Byv9-3Ybh-pwlzpK"
                    device = "/dev/sdb"     # Hint only

                    status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                    flags = []
                    dev_size = 11721045168  # 5.45804 Terabytes
                    pe_start = 2048
                    pe_count = 1430791      # 5.45803 Terabytes
            }
    }
```

So the initial device was `/dev/sdb` but after reboot `lsblk` lists the 6 TB HDD as `/dev/sda`.

The HDD isnt listed as PV also:

`pvs`  only gives `/dev/sdd3  pve lvm2 a--  223.07g    0` which is the SSD where the systems boots from.

`vgs` only gives `pve   1  28   0 wz--n- 223.07g    0`

As mentioned before, I'm absolute beginner in the world of LVM. Is there a chance to get the initial setup restored so I can get access to my media?

Comment: Anything from `pvscan`?

Comment: no there is only the boot SSD